# Como posicionar um componente próximo ao relógio do Windows?

Tags: java, swing

Eu aprendi que para centralizar um componente no centro da tela basta utilizar:

```
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Mas como eu faço para mostrar o componente em cima do relógio do Windows independente do tamanho da tela?

No meu caso o meu código está assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.graphite.GraphiteLookAndFeel");
                mainn frame = new mainn();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Utilizo o *Window Builder* do meu IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Através do método `setLocation(int x, int y)` do seu `JFrame`. Acredito que a sua dúvida seja, na verdade, como obter esses dois valores para então posicionar o componente.

Por meio de um objeto [`GraphicsDevice`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html) você consegue obter o tamanho `x` e `y` da tela onde está sendo executada a aplicação.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MeuJFrame extends JFrame {

    public MeuJFrame(String titulo) {
        super(titulo);
        setSize(400,200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GraphicsDevice tela = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        Rectangle tamanhoTela = tela.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();

        /**
         * Tendo o tamanho da tela, basta subtrair:
         * a) A largura da tela -  largura atual do componente
         * b) A altura da tela  -  altura atual do componente
         */
        int posicaoX = (int) tamanhoTela.getMaxX() - this.getWidth();
        int posicaoY = (int) tamanhoTela.getMaxY() - this.getHeight();

        // E então definir a posição do componente
        setLocation(posicaoX, posicaoY);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new MeuJFrame("StackOverflow").setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

[image: resultado]

Comment: Resolvido! Só não tenho como pontuar. Obrigado!

Comment: Renan. Muito obrigado campeão!

Comment: Entnedi. Desculpa a ignorância kkk.. Obrigado!